# Get data with join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have table in MySQL as bellow:

Table item:

```
id item_name contact_id
1  Cocacola  1;3
2  Clothes   2;3
```

Table contact

```
id name     tel
1  Dona     xxx-xxx-xxxxx
2  Maro     xxx-zzz-zzzzz
3  Sana     yyy-mmm-mmmmm
```

Result need after join:

```
id item_name      contact_tel
1  Cocacola       xxx-xxx-xxxxx, yyy-mmm-mmmmm
2  Clothes        xxx-zzz-zzzzz, yyy-mmm-mmmmm
```

Can I get result like that using join in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  item.id,
  item.item_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tel) contact_tel
FROM
  item LEFT JOIN contact
  ON FIND_IN_SET(contact.id, REPLACE(item.contact_id, ';', ','))
GROUP BY
  item.id,
  item.item_name
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28ddd/4). Performance will be slow, since joining tables using FIND_IN_SET can't make use of an index.